# Progress ABL - What does "?" mean in a method argument?

Tags: c#, progress-4gl, openedge, epicorerp

In my current project, I'm converting some Progress code to C#. One of the statement to convert is:

```
RUN GetNewJobAsmblMultiple IN hIssueReturn(tranType,"?",callProcess,{&input_dataset_SelectedJobAsmblDataSet}, OUTPUT pcMessage, {&output_dataset_IssueReturnDataSet}) NO-ERROR.
```

My questions are:

1. What does the argument "?" means in the method call? What should be the equivalent C# code for it?
2. What does {&input_dataset_SelectedJobAsmblDataSet} mean in the code? Is it some kind of reference? How should this be coded in C#?
3. I assume {&output_dataset_IssueReturnDataSet} is the output variable, and hence in C#, I'm assigning values to it like:  Erp.Tablesets.IssueReturnTableset output_dataset_IssueReturnDataSet =  ...

My code so far has an error for "?", which is suppose to be a GUID:

```
Erp.Tablesets.IssueReturnTableset output_dataset_IssueReturnDataSet = hIssueReturn.GetNewJobAsmblMultiple(tranType, "?", callProcess, ref output_dataset_SelectedJobAsmblDataSet, out pcMessage);
```

SJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"?" is a string literal with the text value of ?

It's different from ? (no quotes) which would be the equivalent to the null value.

{&input_dataset_SelectedPartDataSet} refers to an Include file parameter or an &SCOPED-DEFINE or &GLOBAL-DEFINE definition somewhere else. It's a preprocessor variable.

Comment: I've modified the question, the correct argument was :{&input_dataset_SelectedJobAsmblDataSet}, altough I doubt if it changes your answer.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is the C# service call (added to the question) requires a System.GUID argument, not a string.

Comment: In which environment is your code executed? Is that in a Progress client on Windows that supports .NET calls?

Comment: The code will be running in Epicor ERP 10 using Windows environment.

Comment: "The best overloaded method match for 'Erp.Contracts.IssueReturnSvcContract.GetNewJobAsmblMultiple(string, System.Guid, string, ref Erp.Tablesets.SelectedJobAsmblTableset, out string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Clearly the method is expecting a 'System.Guid pcMtlQueueRowID' object, when I'm providing a string. However, the same method in Progress accepts a string argument for 'pcMtlQueueRowID'. Just not sure what a "?" string means for a rowID in Progress.

Comment: In which case, I assume you'll have to pass System.Guid:NewGuid() for that parameter. I can't answer how your other API behaves on the "?" - as that's dependent on the actual implementation of the API. If you need a GUID in ABL, that's just the GUID keyword. That returns a GUID as CHARACTER.

Comment: That is true, in C#, if the progress code is expecting a new GUID. And this is where I'm stuck, if "?" here represents a new GUID or something else.

Comment: If you ABL session supports GUI for .NET, you can use System.Guid:NewGuid() from within the ABL.    But your question turned into something that's impossible to answer without knowing the actual Epicor implementation of that API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting code that used to run against E9 so it now runs against E10?

In E10.1.400 GetNewJobAsmblMultiple is defined as:

```
    public IssueReturnTableset GetNewJobAsmblMultiple(string pcTranType, Guid pcMtlQueueRowID, string pCallProcess, ref SelectedJobAsmblTableset ds, out string pcMessage)
```

To replicate the same behaviour as E9 pass in Guid.Empty instead of "?". If you have AMM licensed and you pass in a valid GUID for a MtlQueue row the MtlQueue row will be processed with the ttIssueReturn row.

Answer (score 0):

For the question:
  1. What does the argument "?" means in the method call?

The literal question-mark (?) is used by the OpenEdge ABL to mean UNKNOWN.  It is somewhat equivalent to a NULL value in other databases, or in other languages.  As in most languages, a string can be empty ("") or NULL (?) and those are different. Unlike many languages all types can be assigned an UNKNOWN value (?), even a logical -- so a logical boolean can be ?, True, or False (i.e. one of 3 values)

```
def var str as char init ?.

message "string is Unknown" (str EQ ?). // TRUE
message "string is empty" (str EQ "").  // FALSE (NULL and EMPTY are different)

def var log as logical init ?.

message "logical is unknown" (log EQ ?).   // TRUE
message "logical is false" (log EQ FALSE). // Logical is neither FALSE
message "logical is true" (log EQ TRUE).   // nor TRUE
```